# How to execute a program with access to mysql outside of published folder?

Tags: mysql, .net-core, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, ubuntu-18.04

I have a .net core console application that accesses MySQL.  I have compiled the application to run successfully on my raspberry pi, which also hosts the MySQL database.  After I sftp my compiled code to my raspberry pi, I can successfully run the code if I am inside of the folder that contains the application.  However, if I go up a level and try to run the app.  I get an authentication error from MySQL.  For example, inside of my publish folder, I can run ./Application without any issues.  If I go up a level and then run, for example, publish/Application, it fails with the authentication error.

Below is the exception I am getting.

> Unhandled Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Authentication to host '' for user '' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Also below you can see my app settings file that has my connection information.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "TestDB": "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=TestDB;Uid=remote;Pwd=remote"
  }
}
```

Here is also the query I used to grant my user access to the DB.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TestDB.* TO remote@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'remote';
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?  My end goal is to be able to execute the application from any directory in order to add it to the cron daemon.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: " Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) " which means you are trying to login without username or password from MySQL point of view, which may due to any errors while passing username and password.

Comment: Check your username or password as it may be incorrect

Comment: The username and password is correct since it works when running it directly inside of the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have error in connection string.

Try this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "TestDB": "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=TestDB;User=remote;Password=remote"
  }
}
```

I just replaced `Uid` and `Pwd` with `User` and `Password`

Comment: I am getting the same error with this change.  It works fine within the folder that gets pushed from my other machine.  publish/IPTV.  However, when I go up a directory it throws that error.